# How Dependency Property tell the object to apply to?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

(I am totally new to this concept so I may be asking very basic questions.)

A dependency property is registered with the code below:

```
public static DependencyProperty Register(string name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata);
```

Logically, it did nothing but associate a property name with the owner type.

So if I have multiple instances of the owner type, and each instance set the DP to different values.

How could these values be stored?

### Update 1 - 10:04 AM 10/30/2013

I read about the Attached Property from here: http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

> Attached Properties
>
> Attached properties are a special kind of DependencyProperties. They
>   allow you to attach a value to an object that does not know anything
>   about this value.
>
> A good example for this concept are layout panels. Each layout panel
>   needs different data to align its child elements. The Canvas needs Top
>   and Left, The DockPanel needs Dock, etc. Since you can write your own
>   layout panel, the list is infinite. So you see, it's not possible to
>   have all those properties on all WPF controls.
>
> The solution are attached properties. They are defined by the control
>   that needs the data from another control in a specific context. For
>   example an element that is aligned by a parent layout panel.

So in the following code snippet:

```
<Canvas>
    <Button Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Content="Click me!"/>
    <Button Canvas.Top="40" Canvas.Left="20" Content="Click me!"/>
</Canvas>
```

Apparently we cannot give all the align properties such as **Top**, **Left** to Button. So Canvas defines such properties and they are "**attached**" to Button control.

When Canvas.Top is specified as an "attribute" of the Button in XAML, it will invoke the SetTop() method which is defined in the Canvas type. And the Button is passed in as the element argument.
**I think that's how Canvas knows which Button use which Top value.**

```
public static void SetTop(UIElement element, double length);
```

**But I don't see why the Attached Property has to be a Dependency Property?**  What's the connection between them?

Thanks!

Comment: That's done by class [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.aspx). You can't set a dependency property on any object that is not a DependencyObject. DependencyObject defines the methods GetValue and SetValue (and a few others) to get/set dependency property values. It is all explained in the [Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: This is one of the best tutorials I have ever read about exactly such questions. And its plain english. :) http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html What you should remember, you dont have to care much whats happening under the hood, all you need to know is that there are dictionaries and hashsets defined globally which maintain dependency properties. Those guys are so bad ass, they run extremly fast, allow inheritance of properties, animation of properties and dependency property value precedence. :) Btw, like Clemens already said, without DependencyObject the concept wouldnt work.

Comment: "But I don't see why the Attached Property has to be a Dependency Property?". Simply because getting and setting the value of an attached  property is also done by `DependencyObject.GetValue` and `DependencyObject.SetValue`. `Canvas.SetTop(e, t)` just calls `e.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, t)`.

Comment: That is all explained in the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: @smwikipedia - Attached property is a dependency property since it also needs to support binding, animation and property metadata. Isn't that fair enough?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when we define a `DependencyProperty`, we also define a CLR 'wrapper' that enables us to use the `DependencyProperty` in code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), typeof(MainWindow), 
     new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<string>()));

public ObservableCollection<string> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}
```

Here you can see the `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods that @Clemens was talking about. We get access to these methods in a `Window` and/or `UserControl` because they both extend the `DependencyObject` class. You can also see that the `Items` property here is *not* `static`... it is just the definition of the `DependencyProperty` that is `static`.

---

UPDATE >>>

There's not really much point in asking *why does an Attached Property have to be a `DependencyProperty`?* because in .NET, they just are... they were just designed like that. A better question might be, *what benefit does an Attached Property get from being a `DependencyProperty`?*

The answer to that would be the same as if asked *what benefit does a property get from being a `DependencyProperty`?* The main benefits being that these properties can be used in `Binding`s, `Style`s, `Animation`s and `Resources` among other things. More details can be found from the (already linked to in the comments) two very important pages on MSDN for any WPF developers:

[Dependency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Please note that it is considered bad practice to set a default value by property metadata for collection type dependency properties. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970563.aspx#initializing) for an explanation.

Comment: +1 @Clemens, thanks so much for that tip... very interesting stuff. I'm always keen to find out something new. I've never come across that problem because most of my `DependencyProperty`s are defined in view models where only one instance is used at a time, but if I had come across it, I'd have been stumped. I simplified my code example. Thanks again.

Comment: @Sheridan Thanks much. I have updated my post with further question.

Comment: @smwikipedia Instead of "updating your post with further question" you should better ask a new one, as the original question has already been answered here.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question I need to start from the very basics of Dependency system (you already know most of these things below, but I think after reading it your question might answer itself)

`DependencyProperty` should be defined within a class that is derived from `DependencyObject` because `DependencyObject` implements some methods and members (which most of them are private and developers can't see them). These implementations provide the `DependencyObject` with the abilities to store and retrieve data with static reference to the class (instead of reference to an instance of the class)

The way we store and retrive data is either through the `DependencyProperty`'s wrapper or directly by GetValue and SetValue (which are `DependencyObject`'s methods) or through bindings. Either way the static `DependencyProperty` is the "key" to find the proper value.

When you register a `DependencyProperty`, the Dependency system is informed that a new `DependencyProperty` is added to its resources (something like a list, filled with DependencyProperties that you've registerd). Now if you store something as `[this.]SetValue(MyProperty, value)`, you're essentially updating a resource of object `this` (which you can imagine as `this.Resources[MyProperty]`).

This works just like a normal property on the outside, but considering the `UIPropertyMetadata` and other `Dependency` stuff, your `DependencyProperty` is equipped with a handful of unique abilities to Coerce, participate in animations, notify when changed and etc and can do much more than a simple property.

remember extension?

```
public static void MyExtension(this MyType target, string parameter, ...)
{
    target.MyFunction(parameter, ...);
}
var t = new MyType();
t.MyExtension("test");
```

`AttachedProperty` is somehow the combination of `DependencyProperty` and extension, with some differences:

1. Wrappers of `AttachedProperty` are static and take a class reference as input to know where are they attached. The target of a `DependencyProperty` is usually `this` (unless you change GetValue and SetValue to something like `otherObject.SetValue(MyProperty, value)` ). but unlike `DependencyProperty`, The target of an `AttachedProperty` (which have to be a `DependencyObject` itself) is being passed to it as a parameter. and again the reason it has to be a `DependencyObject` is that only a `DependencyObject` is capable of having a set of resources to store a `DependencyProperty` in.
2. unlike `DependencyProperty` which uses `Register`, `AttachedProperty` uses `RegisterAttached` method which tells the Dependency System that other `DependencyObject`s can have this property but still the actual static property is stored in `DependencyObject` which has the `AttachedProperty`.
3. in Extension, `this` before its first parameter is used to "extend" the type next to it. in `AttachedProperty` there's no `this`, in fact it's always the `DependencyObject` class which is extended.
4. Unlike `AttachedProperty`, an extension can't store data by itself unless you write a few lines of code similar to the implementation of the `AttachedProperty`. e.g. implementing a static list of `KeyValuePairs` (Value for the actual data and Key for knowing to whom do they belong)

---

Edit:

After Clemens's comment I need to add that `AttachedProperty` is not actually an extension. the reason I brought up extension is that by comparing these two, you can see the reason why a normal property can't be attached to a `DependencyObject` because in order to store data in other objects, some collection like a Resource is needed (which `DependencyObject` has).

Comment: Attached properties and extension methods are completely unrelated, and saying that "attached properties are somehow a combination of dependency properties and extension (methods)" is wrong. The simple fact that CLR wrappers for attached properties are static methods does in no way create a relation to extension methods.

Comment: Extensions are simple static methods with a few additional behaviors just like attached properties. They act similar to each other by enabling something for an object which it doesn't have. the differences lies in the implementations of dependency object class.

Comment: "with a few additional behaviors just like attached properties". This is vague and confusing and at best shows that you haven't fully understood the two different concepts. The only thing that CLR wrappers for attached properties and extension methods have in common is that they are static methods. That's all.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here Clemens, I'm trying to help 'smwikipedia' understand why attached property has to be dependency property and why it can't be a normal property because it looks like extension. I'm not saying they're the same, but one can implement a non-dependency attached property using extension and some code.

Comment: But you're right, it was misleading and thanks for your comment, I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I've always viewed `DependencyProperties` as a property definition, which is different from a normal property.

The property definition contains the property type, name, default value, etc and includes a pointer showing where to find the property value. But it doesn't contain the value itself.

This allows you to use `DependencyProperties` in Bindings, since you can set the property up to get its value from a bound expression instead of from the object itself.

This is important for `AttachedProperties` because their value doesn't reside on the object they are attached to. They need the ability to look up their value in a different location than the object itself, and `DependencyProperties` allow this.

You can't do this with a regular property because a normal property's value is meant to be found on the object itself, but an `AttachedProperty` doesn't exist on the object it's attached to.

That's the simple version. :)