# wpf how exactly do static dependency properties back properties of an instance property?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I guess I never thought to question it before, but it seems weird that you can store different values for a property on each instance of a control even though though the static property that was registered was only registered once. Is the property in the dictionary actually stored under another dictionary that keeps track of which object corresponds to which value of the property?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Dependency Property tell the object to apply to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19662525/how-dependency-property-tell-the-object-to-apply-to)

Comment: It's all explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

Comment: so the gist of it is that the resource dictionary is not global like i was thinking, but a dictionary under the dependency object, so there are separate dictionaries for each object? or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: ResourceDictionaries have nothing to do with the inner workings of DependencyProperties, you seem to be confusing these concepts

Comment: sorry i meant to just say dictionary. this is the relevant answer from the page right?

"All types that want to use DependencyProperties must derive from DependencyObject. This baseclass defines a key, value dictionary that contains local values of dependency properties. The key of an entry is the key defined with the dependency property."